# Пара вопросов по MySQL на которые не нашел точного ответа

Tags: mysql, база-данных

*При проектировании MySQL БД возникло несколько вопросов:*

1. Необходимо ли указывать `DEFAULT NULL`, есть колонка `birthday DATE NULL` ?
2. Нужно ли писать `NOT NULL` если поле `AUTO_INCREMENT` или `PRIMARY KEY` ?
3. Если таблица/база в `UTF-8`, нужно ли полю `data BINARY` присваивать `COLLATE 'binary'` ?
4. Есть поле `country_code` или `email`, значения возможны только латиницей, стоит ли присваивать кодировку `latin1`, а также на что еще влияет изменения кодировки кроме как дополнительной фильтрации вводных данных ?
5. Нужно ли писать `NOT NULL` колонке `thumbnail VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'no_thumbnail.jpg'` если указано значение по умолчанию ?
6. В чем отличия поведения между `UNIQUE (actor_id,user_id)` и `PRIMARY KEY (actor_id,user_id)` ?

*Буду благодарен за подробный ответ*

Comment: 1) Нет 2) Да, если есть FK на поле, иначе необязательно 3) Необязательно, но явное указание всегда надёжнее 4) Необязательно 5) Да 6) Для PK поля обязаны быть NOT NULL

Comment: @Akina вот что заметил при создании таблицы в GUI интерфейсе DataGrid *(JetBrains)*, если задать `AUTO_INCREMENT` убирается значение `NULL`, но при добавлении `PRIMARY KEY`, не добавляется `NOT NULL`, что вводит меня в заблуждение, так как в случае с PostgreSQL в `PK` уже включен `NOT NULL`, а вот с MySQL не понятно имеет ли PK constraint

Comment: @Akina Или в случае `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` значение `NOT NULL` не обязательно ?

Comment: *заметил при создании таблицы в GUI интерфейсе* GUI не имеет отношения к серверу. Совсем. Всё, что там происходит, на совести его авторов. *Или в случае AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY значение NOT NULL не обязательно ?* Для поля AUTO_INCREMENT вставка NULL означает генерацию следующего значения. Так что NULL более чем бессмыслен. А на самом деле... создайте таблицу с таким полем, а потом сразу посмотрите код её создания. Сюрприз будет.